# Why does the Inner Join query not work while multi where clause does

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, postgresql-9.3

Lets say I run a crooked car company. Let's say I have the following table:
`car_engine_mileage_counters` which is a join table from `car_engines` onto `mileage_counters` also storing a calculated field of `mileage`
Lets also say that I encode a coefficient at the engine block level in my factory on an `engine template`.

```
UPDATE car_engine_mileage_counters
SET mileage = mileage_counters.mileage * coefficients.coefficient
FROM car_engines
INNER JOIN engine_templates
ON car_engines.template_id = engine_templates.id
INNER JOIN mileage_counters
ON mileage_counters.id = car_engine_mileage_counters.mileage_counter_id
INNER JOIN mileage_counter_templates
ON mileage_counter.template_id = mileage_counter_templates.id
INNER JOIN coefficients
ON coefficients.mileage_counter_template_id = mileage_counter_templates.id
WHERE coefficients.engine_template_id = engine_template.id AND car_engines.id = car_engine_mileage_counters.engine_id;
```

This (clearly fictitious) example fails with:

> ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table
>   "car_engine_mileage_counters"
>       LINE 7: ON mileage_counters.id = car_engine_mileage_counters...
>                                          ^
>       HINT:  There is an entry for table "measure_instances_question_instances", but it cannot be referenced
>   from this part of the query.

Enumerating all tables in a single `FROM` clause, and using `WHERE AND` in place of all `INNER JOIN`s however works fine.

My question is, why? What is wrong with the inner join query? How can I fix it? Does it matter?

Comment: You cannot do a join clause on `car_engine_mileage_counters` in line 7 because it's not a part of your from clause.

Comment: Adding an alias to the target table (and to all the source tables ...) is the simplest solution. It will also increase readability, IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE cem
SET mileage = mileage_counters.mileage * coefficients.coefficient
FROM car_engine_mileage_counters cem
INNER JOIN car_engines 
ON car_engines.id = cem.engine_id
INNER JOIN engine_templates
ON car_engines.template_id = engine_templates.id
INNER JOIN mileage_counters
ON mileage_counters.id = cem.mileage_counter_id
INNER JOIN mileage_counter_templates
ON mileage_counter.template_id = mileage_counter_templates.id
INNER JOIN coefficients
ON coefficients.mileage_counter_template_id = mileage_counter_templates.id
WHERE coefficients.engine_template_id = engine_template.id AND car_engines.id = cem.engine_id;
```